# I want to generate geopoints after parsing XML using SAX Parser

Tags: android

I am able to parse XML using SAX Parser and able to display the points in text view.
But now I want the points to be displayed on the map.The XML Contains tags for latitude and longitude.
I want to read the latitiudes and longitudes and display them on map.

**UPDATE:**

```
public void parsing()
{
    try
    {
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(handler);
    InputStream in=this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.poi);
    xr.parse(new InputSource(in));
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        System.out.println("XML Parsing Excpetion = " + e);

}
    poilist=XMLHandler.POIList;
    ArrayList<Integer> Latitude=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> Longtitude=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<poilist.getlat().size();i++)
    {
        Latitude.add(i);
        Longtitude.add(i);
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass these latitude and longitude values to the Geopoint..
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
```

The above line of code will give you a [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) object with the latitude and longitude you pass to the constructor.  GeoPoint belongs to the Google Maps API add-on.  After you create the GeoPoint, you add it to a map overlay on the MapView.

You should check out Google's explination and example of doing this.
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: But i have one more problem .I have read XMl and stored the result in array list and used GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng); ... But after parsing XML ,i have stored values in array list,but somehow i am not able to use the array list with GeoPoint...Do u have any clue about this??

Comment: I would have to see the code to understand what you're trying to do.